# Is Historical (or narrative) Present Used in Tanakh?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, tanach, language

In the beginning of ויצא, the first couple of verses are written in past tense but Yaakov's dream is in present tense. I assumed that a possible explanation for this is that the Torah is using the literary technique called [historical present](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Historical_present) which is "typically thought to heighten the dramatic force of the narrative by describing events as if they were still unfolding, and/or by foregrounding some events relative to others." (Wikipedia)

1. Is this an accurate explanation of these pesukim?
2. Do any traditional sources state this?
3. Do any traditional sources mention this technique in connection to Tanakh?

Comment: The "present tense" is actually participles, which are non-finite verb forms, unmarked for aspect or tense.

Comment: @magicker72 can you explain what that means? I only know very basic grammar...

Comment: It means that the tense (past, present, future, etc) of a participle (like אוֹמֵר) is gleaned from context rather than baked in to the verb.

Comment: @magicker72 So in this case the words in the third passuk (like עולים ויורדים בו) are actually past tense due to context?

Comment: Could be. Or it could be timeless (as in this is something that always happens). I'm not purporting to answer that question.

Comment: @magicker72 I just read a bit about participles. Don't they have to serve as an adjective?  That would fit with עולים ויורדים בו?